# Ocmod, правка файла стилей

Tags: php, opencart

Пытаюсь поменять стили через ocmod, и проблема в том, что изменённый файл стилей появляется в папке модификаций `system/storage/modification/catalog/view/theme/theme_lightshop/css/main.css`, но при открытии сайта, файл стилей `main.css` остаётся прежний.
Из-за чего это может быть?
Как правильно поправить файл стилей из ocmod?

```
<modification>
    ...
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/theme_lightshop/css/main.css">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[
.nav-submenu-slider__inner .slick-prev,.nav-submenu-slider__inner .slick-next {
            ]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[.row.nav-submenu__full-width {
    letter-spacing: normal!important;
}
.nav-submenu {
    padding: 26px 0 16px;
    max-width:none;
}]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

opencart 2.3 установлен

другие изменения в этом же файле ocmod меняют код нормально:

```
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/theme_lightshop/template/common/currency.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[
<div class="header__currencies <?php echo count($currencies) < 2 ? 'header__currencies--hide' : ''?>">
            ]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
<div class="header__currencies <?php echo count($currencies) < 2 ? 'header__currencies--hide' : ''?>" style="display:none">
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью oCmod, как и vQmod, нельзя изменять css и js файлы. Если необходимо изменять стили с помощью модификаторов, то вносите изменения в файл шаблона header, добавляя стили инлайн или подключая свой файл css.